# In Whitehead & Russell's PM, does every Series contain a $P_1$ (immedeately precedes)?

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations

✳204.7 $\vdash: P \in Ser .\supset. P_1 \in 1 \rightarrow 1$

Which says if $P$ is a series, then $P_1$ is one-one.

---

✳201.63 $\vdash: P \in trans \cap Rl‘J .\supset. P_1 = P \overset{.}{-}P^2$

Which says if $P$ is transitive and asymetrical, then $P_1=P\overset{.}{-}P^2$

---

Where

$P_1$ is "immediately precedes" as defined in ✳121.02 :

✳121.02 $P_v = \hat{x} \hat{y}\{ N_0c‘P(x|-|y)=v+_c1 \}$ Df where $v=1$

and $P^2 = P|P$ as defined in ✳34.02

---

Let R be "less than confined to the real interval [0,1],"  then R is transitive, asymmetrical and connected. Therefore, by definition, $R$ is a series. But there is no term in $R$'s field that immediately precedes any other terms. In other words, $R_1$ does not seem to exist. If I'm not mistaken, the premises of 204.7 should include $\overset{.}{\exists}!P_1$ as a hypothesis.

Comment: OK. According to ✳250.21, every term in a well-ordered series(except for the last) has an immediate successor. That means even if ✳204.7 missed the hypothesis, it has no impact on well-ordered series, because $\Omega$ always contains a $P_1$.

Comment: But I do not understand your : "immediately precedes **any** other terms". In the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers $0$ precedes **any** other term (different from itself) but **not** immediately:  $0 < 5$ but the "immediate" predeceswsor of $5$ is $4$. Of couse, my "reading" of your question may be wrong...

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. $Ser$ is defined at 204.01. A series is a relation that is asymmetrical, transitive and connected. < over the field [0,1] is a series, but 0.5 (for example) has no immediate neighbours. No matter how close its neighbour(say, 0.500001) is to 0.5, there are always infinitely many other terms in between.

Comment: A series does not have to be discrete. That is why I think $P_1$'s existence is not guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, but then $[0,1]$ is a series and by [Well-ordering Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) we can order it. Clearly $0$ *precedes* **any** other term, but the Th is non-constructive: thus it gives us no clue about the way of finding the *immediate* predecessor of $1$.

Comment: That's a good point. But, the way 204.7 puts it, $P$ does not have to be well ordered. According to 201.63, if the series is continuous, $P_1=\overset{.}{\Lambda}$

Comment: I still think that in your question there is a typo : "there is no term in R's field that immediately precedes any other terms" is *true*: no number can "immediately" precede any other, because [see ✳204.7] $P_1$ is one-one. It must be  "for any term (except $0$) there is a term that precedes it", and this is true according to W-O Th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well the definition, it is trivial that in $[0,1]$ there is an element which *precedes* any other element : it is $0$.

But to say that for any element different from $0$ there is an *immediate predecessor*, we have to use something like the [Well-ordering Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) proved by Zermelo in 1904 (thus known to W&R at time of writing *PM*) using the *Axiom of Choice* (the *Multiplicative Axiom* in *PM*).

This theorem says that any set can be well-ordered, and so also $[0,1]$.

But the proof is non-constructive: thus it gives us no clue about the way of finding the immediate predecessor of (say) $1$.

Comment: 202.7 has the same problem.

Comment: I think there is a problem. See 202.7, step (3), the implication is true, but the premises are not necessarily true. In other words, given an $x$, there may not exist a $y$ such that $y(P\overset{.}{-}P^2)x$. This is the kind of mistake W&R have been warning against throughout the whole volumes.

Comment: But I think this mistake is inconsequential.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - according to Zermelo's proof of the well-ordering theorem, every set can be well-ordered. A set X is well-ordered by a strict total order if every non-empty subset of X has a least element under the ordering. Thus, consider $X \subset [0,1]$ containing all the $r$ such that $r > 0$. Thus $X$ has a least element $x_0$ (but we cannot say which ..). Then $x_0$ is the *immediate successor* of $0$. The same apply for the *immediate predecessor* of $1$ ...

Comment: W-O Th says there exist a relation that can W-O the field, it does not say all relations can W-O the same field. "<" is definitely not W-O. Maybe x2 can do that.

Comment: Let R stand for $\times 2$, then 0.4 $R$ 0.2, and 0.2 $R$ 0.1, thus 0.2 has immediate neighbours. R is W-O, but is not a series, because it breaks up the field into several series, i.e. not connected.

Comment: The problem is in the last step of 202.7. There is no reason to drop the hypothesis because it is never asserted.

Comment: Surpise! See 72.1 $\vdash. \overset{.}{\Lambda}\in 1\rightarrow 1$. That means even if $P_1$ is $\overset{.}{\Lambda}$, it is still one-one.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - see page 498 (vol.II) : in a *compact* (i.e. not *discrete*) series $P_1 = \overset{.}{\Lambda}$ and, as you have verified : $\overset{.}{\Lambda} \in 1 \to 1$.

Comment: Found it. Thanks, @Mauro! It's *201.65, page 532(vol.II) Merchant Books 1912.

Comment: *258 showed how to construct a W-O series over a given field. I haven't figure out how to construct the selector generically. I just pick one out of the previous class and the remaining terms form another class, and so on, assuming the selector $S$ exists. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/961802/119110

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $\mu$,

Let $Q=\hat{ \alpha}\hat{\beta}\{\alpha,\beta \in Cl_{ex}‘\mu.\beta \subset \alpha.\beta \neq \alpha \}$

Let $S \in \epsilon_\Delta‘Cl_{ex}‘\mu$

Let $R=\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta}\{\alpha \in Cl_{ex}‘\mu.\beta=\alpha - \iota ‘S‘\alpha \}$

Then $Q_{R\mu}$ is $Q$ confined to the transfinite posterity of $\mu$, and $S^;Q_{R\mu}$ is Well-ordered over the field of $\mu$.

To construct $S^;Q_{R\mu}$, all we need is to construct a selector $S$ which selects one term out of each of $\mu$'s subclasses.

[image]